# Doing a Templated Mail Merge in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, facelets

I want to have a Java facelet that has EL expressions, and a set of beans that are email recipients. Then I want to loop through the recipients and render the facelet, getting the HTML out the other side. Then I will send the HTML to Amazon SES which will send the email.

Seam has classes for sending emails but you cannot just have it render your template.

I know back in the days of JSP, it was not possible to just render a view in line, but I think with facelets this might be possible. If not, open to other ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it may be a bit outdated, [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) is primarily a framework for rendering template files given some set of inputs.

Comment: Agreed on this one and the others as well, 'interesting' approach though ... - while not illegal, providing a multitude of answers like this is quite unusual (to say the least), rather it seems common to strive for a balanced canonical one for questions that have no single answer; I suggest you try the same, right now I'm unable to decide which answer deserves an up vote ;)

Comment: Agree with @Steffan. I had remembered FreeMarker and thought about looking at that. Steffan, do you know if it's possible to just render a facelet and get the results on the server side? Not possible with JSP because of its dependence on some server/view stuff, but thought maybe it was possible with facelets.

Comment: You can use Freemarker completely independently of JSP. I'm confused as to where you're attempting to render the e-mail which is being sent, server- or client-side?

Comment: I don't even understand the idea of rendering client side to send a batch email… ?

Comment: Okay, good, we're together on that one... I'm just having a hard time understanding your talk about rendering a facelet and getting the resulting HTML for sending. Isn't a facelet just a special case of a servlet/jsp? (this being said, I have very little knowledge of JSF)

Comment: Yeah and believe it or not you could not just send a JSP through a renderer and get the result in a server-side Java app. I think you can with a servlet because it doesn't depend on a bunch of crap that is only there when the client runs.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an implementation of [{{ Mustache }}](http://mustache.github.com/) available for usage in Java applications. [{{ here }}](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java)

Comment: Looks interesting, though I would like something that used JSF if possible. Don't have a JS need for this since this is all happening server side.

Comment: Mustache does have a java implementation which can be used on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

[Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is an JavaScript-based extension/implementation of Mustache which can be used to render templates completely from the client side. (*if that's something you're looking for*)